# complex sql query assistance wordpress

Tags: sql

I have to add two condition from other two tables to this query but i don't know how to do it.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND ( (
                SELECT COUNT(1)
                FROM wp_term_relationships
                WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (2,3)
                AND object_id = wp_posts.ID
                ) = 2 ) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'packages' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

other tables:

> table 1 (name:packages_dates) has three field :
>   post_id,date_from(date),date_to(date)
>
> table 2 (name:packages_price) has two field : post_id,price(numeric)

the condition are:

i have a date input and that must be between date_from and date_to in

> table 1

;

second input is a range of price that must include price in

> table 2

;

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your database allows for inner joins, then it seems to me like this should work:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM wp_posts inner join packages_dates on wp_posts.ID=packages_dates.post_id inner join packages_price on wp_posts.ID=packages_price.post_id WHERE 1=1  AND ( (
            SELECT COUNT(1)
            FROM wp_term_relationships
            WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (2,3)
            AND object_id = wp_posts.ID
            ) = 2 ) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'packages' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') AND packages_dates.date_from >=DateInput and packages_dates.date_to<=DateInput and packages_price between InputLowRange and InputHighRange GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```